# How to disable fullscreen button in Mac OS in SWT / Java App?

Tags: java, macos, swt, fullscreen

I am working on SWT app. It works fine on windows, but when I run the same code on mac.
I get a full screen button on right corner of my shell.

[image]

On clicking that full screen button the app stop responding and nothing happens. I want to disable the click on that fullscreen button.

```
display = Display.getDefault();
shell = new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);        
setDialogShell(shell);
getDialogShell().setLayout( new FormLayout());
getDialogShell().setFullScreen(false);
```

Please help. I have gone through this some [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/928169/) but didn't got how to disable that full screen button in mac.

Comment: Is your JVM the Oracle Java by any chance? I just found out that the hanging only happens when the SWT app is running on the Oracle JVM. It works fine using the old Apple JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display = Display.getDefault();
shell = new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
//Shell shell = window.getShell();
NSWindow nswindow = shell.view.window();
nswindow.setCollectionBehavior(0);  
nswindow.setShowsResizeIndicator(false);
setDialogShell(shell);
getDialogShell().setLayout( new FormLayout());
getDialogShell().setFullScreen(false);
```

This worked for me..

**** **EDIT** *****************************

The above code is not running in windows, as no recognised "NSWindow" class.
For using common code for both window and mac use the below code.

```
public static boolean isWindows() {

      return (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0);

     }
```

/// Check if OS is Window, Then change the code as follow

```
display = Display.getDefault();
        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
         //Shell shell = window.getShell();


        if(!isWindows()){
            Field field = Control.class.getDeclaredField("view");
            Object /*NSView*/ view = field.get(shell);
            if (view != null)
            {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView");
                Object /*NSWindow*/ window = c.getDeclaredMethod("window").invoke(view);

                c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow");
                Method setCollectionBehavior = c.getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setCollectionBehavior", /*JVM.is64bit() ?*/ long.class /*: int.class*/);
                setCollectionBehavior.invoke(window,0);
            }
            //          NSWindow nswindow = shell.view.window();
            //          nswindow.setCollectionBehavior(0) ; 
            //          nswindow.setShowsResizeIndicator(false);
        }
        setDialogShell(shell);
        getDialogShell().setLayout( new FormLayout());
        getDialogShell().setFullScreen(false);

        getDialogShell().layout();
        getDialogShell().pack();
```