# Eclipse SWT how to disable "fullscreen" on Shell on MacOS 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: widget, swt, fullscreen, osx-yosemite, expand

There are a lot of answered questions about how to disable resize (which I already did), but the new feature that Apple added, to expand the dialog (little green dot with arrows pointing up-right and down-left). This button is always enabled, despite various options that I tried, like

```
SWT.DIALOG_TRIM, 

SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE

SWT.CLOSE

...
```

What is the correct style that I have to apply to the Shell constructor, in order to get the "expand" (or whatever this action is called) on MacOS 10.10 to be disabled?

Edit: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834207/how-to-disable-fullscreen-button-in-mac-os-in-swt-java-app) helped me, I used the common code for Windows and Mac, and just as a note, the "Field" and the "Method" objects needs to be imported from java.lang.reflect package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pop-up dialog

```
SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL
```

(the default for a non-resizable `Dialog`) disables the green dot.

For the main application Shell I am not sure that you can control this with flags, although you may be able to use Mac specific code as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14834207/2670892) question.

Comment: Thanks, the link that you provided did the trick. I guess I should've searched for "disable fullscreen" as opposed to "disable expand", that's why I did not get any relevant results.